# How to avoid a Toast if there's one Toast already being shown

Tags: android, android-toast

I have several `SeekBar` and `onSeekBarProgressStop()`, I want to show a `Toast` message.

But if on `SeekBar` I perform the action rapidly then UI thread somehow blocks and `Toast` message waits till UI thread is free.

Now my concern is to avoid the new `Toast` message if the `Toast` message is already displaying. Or is their any condition by which we check that UI thread is currently free then I'll show the `Toast` message.

I tried it in both way, by using `runOnUIThread()` and also creating new `Handler`.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I've tried a variety of things to do this. At first I tried using the `cancel()`, which had no effect for me (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7235755/1276636)).

With `setDuration(n)` I wasn't coming to anywhere either. It turned out by logging `getDuration()` that it carries a value of 0 (if `makeText()`'s parameter was `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT`) or 1 (if `makeText()`'s parameter was `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`).

Finally I tried to check if the toast's view `isShown()`. Of course it isn't if no toast is shown, but even more, it returns a fatal error in this case. So I needed to try and catch the error. 
Now, `isShown()` returns true if a toast is displayed.
Utilizing `isShown()` I came up with the method:

```
    /**
     * <strong>public void showAToast (String st)</strong></br>
     * this little method displays a toast on the screen.</br>
     * it checks if a toast is currently visible</br>
     * if so </br>
     * ... it "sets" the new text</br>
     * else</br>
     * ... it "makes" the new text</br>
     * and "shows" either or  
     * @param st the string to be toasted
     */

    public void showAToast (String st){ //"Toast toast" is declared in the class
        try{ toast.getView().isShown();     // true if visible
            toast.setText(st);
        } catch (Exception e) {         // invisible if exception
            toast = Toast.makeText(theContext, st, toastDuration);
            }
        toast.show();  //finally display it
    }
```

Comment: Good answer. One remark: The reason isShown() "raises an exception" is that toast.getView() initially returns null. Simply test for null as opposed to using try...catch.

Comment: You may consider doing a straight check rather than try/catch as this is a expected and common situation.

Comment: See my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29573861/2457744) for how to do it without to try/catch.

Comment: When i am using Toast.LENGTH_SHORT it`s not working, after using Toast.LENGTH_LONG working fine.

Comment: Toast.getView() always returns null on Android 11+ (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62884286/toast-getview-returns-null-on-android-11-api-30), so this solution is obsolete

Answer (score 46):

The following is an alternative solution to the [most popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925156/how-to-avoid-a-toast-if-theres-one-toast-already-being-shown/11441738#11441738), without the try/catch.

```
public void showAToast (String message){
        if (mToast != null) {
            mToast.cancel();
        }
        mToast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        mToast.show();
}
```

Comment: the best, thnx!

Answer (score 4):

A clean solution that works out of the box. Define this on your Activity:

```
private Toast toast;

/**
 * Use this to prevent multiple Toasts from spamming the UI for a long time.
 */
public void showToast(CharSequence text, int duration)
{
    if (toast == null)
        toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);
    else
        toast.setText(text);
    toast.show();
}

public void showToast(int resId, int duration)
{
    showToast(getResources().getText(resId), duration);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

keep track of the last time you showed the toast, and make re-showing it a no-op if it falls within some interval.

```
public class RepeatSafeToast {

    private static final int DURATION = 4000;

    private static final Map<Object, Long> lastShown = new HashMap<Object, Long>();

    private static boolean isRecent(Object obj) {
        Long last = lastShown.get(obj);
        if (last == null) {
            return false;
        }
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (last + DURATION < now) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static synchronized void show(Context context, int resId) {
        if (isRecent(resId)) {
            return;
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, resId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        lastShown.put(resId, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public static synchronized void show(Context context, String msg) {
        if (isRecent(msg)) {
            return;
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        lastShown.put(msg, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

and then,

```
RepeatSafeToast.show(this, "Hello, toast.");
RepeatSafeToast.show(this, "Hello, toast."); // won't be shown
RepeatSafeToast.show(this, "Hello, toast."); // won't be shown
RepeatSafeToast.show(this, "Hello, toast."); // won't be shown
```

this isn't perfect, since the length of `LENGTH_SHORT` and `LENGTH_LONG` are undefined, but it works well in practice. it has the advantage over other solutions that you don't need to hold on to the Toast object and the call syntax remains terse.

Comment: Sweet, exactly what I was looking for. Works great.

Comment: Maybe good idea, but not implemented perfectly. You are putting objects in HashMap, but not removing them.

Comment: since the key is the string that's being toasted, the size of the map is limited by the number of strings being toasted. your point is valid only if you are toasting dynamic strings ("foo bar" + i). if you need better, replace HashMap with LruCache.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is:

```
public class Utils {
    public static Toast showToast(Context context, Toast toast, String str) {
        if (toast != null)
            toast.cancel();
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
        return t;
    }
}
```

and the caller should have a Toast member for this method's parameter, or

```
class EasyToast {
    Toast toast;
    Context context;

    public EasyToast(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Toast show(String str) {
        if (toast != null)
            toast.cancel();
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
        return t;
    }

}
```

have a helper class like this.

Comment: I came to the same solution. If isShown() doesn't work as expected then just don't use it :) and cancel() the toast if it's not null.

Answer (score 2):

The enhanced function from above thread, which will show toast only if not visible with same text message:

```
 public void showSingleToast(){
        try{
            if(!toast.getView().isShown()) {    
                toast.show();
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();       
            Log.d(TAG,"Toast Exception is "+exception.getLocalizedMessage());
            toast = Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(),   getContext().getString(R.string.no_search_result_fou`enter code here`nd), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### A combined solution

For my case, I needed to cancel the current toast if it shown and display another one.

This was to solve the scenario when the user asks for a service while it is still loading or not available I need to show a toast (might me different if the requested service is different). Otherwise, the toasts will keep showing in order and it will take a very long time to hide them automatically.

So basically I save the instance of the toast am creating and the following code is how to cancel it safly

```
synchronized public void cancel() {
    if(toast == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "cancel: toast is null (occurs first time only)" );
        return;
    }
    final View view = toast.getView();
    if(view == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "cancel: view is null");
        return;
    }
    if (view.isShown()) {
        toast.cancel();
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "cancel: view is already dismissed");
    }
}
```

And to use it I can now not worry about cancelling as in:

```
if (toastSingleton != null ) {
    toastSingleton.cancel();
    toastSingleton.showToast(messageText);
}else{
    Log.e(TAG, "setMessageText: toastSingleton is null");
}
```

The **showToast** is up to you how to implement it as I needed a custom look for my toast.

Comment: True logic and true check for null view before check if it is shown. And multiple calls for showing a toast is a long weird experience especially if the user is already out of the app. Must cancel current then invoke a new one as you mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Good for stopping stacking e.g. click driven toast. Based off @Addi's answer.

```
public Toast toast = null;
//....
public void favsDisplay(MenuItem item)
{
    if(toast == null) // first time around
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Some text...";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    }
    try
    {
        if(toast.getView().isShown() == false) // if false not showing anymore, then show it
            toast.show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for showing toast message on screen either it is displayed or not.
For Showing a toast message Make a separate class. And use the method of this class which display the toast message after checking the visibility of the toast message. Use This Snippet of code:

```
public class AppToast {

private static Toast toast;

public static void showToast(Context context, String message) {
    try {
        if (!toast.getView().isShown()) {
            toast=Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        toast=Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}

}
```

I hope this solution will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

added timer to remove the toast after 2 seconds.

```
private Toast toast;

public void showToast(String text){
        try {
            toast.getView().isShown();
            toast.setText(text);
        }catch (Exception e){
            toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        if(toast.getView().isShown()){
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    toast.cancel();
                }
            }, 2000);
        }else{
            toast.show();
        }
    }

showToast("Please wait");
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for Android 11+ (API level 30 and above)

`Toast.getView()` is [deprecated since API level 30](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#getView()):

> This method was deprecated in API level 30. Custom toast views are
> deprecated. Apps can create a standard text toast with the
> makeText(android.content.Context, java.lang.CharSequence, int) method,
> or use a Snackbar when in the foreground. Starting from Android
> Build.VERSION_CODES#R, apps targeting API level Build.VERSION_CODES#R
> or higher that are in the background will not have custom toast views
> displayed.

If you want to avoid Toast overlapping, you could save the time the last Toast was shown using `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Here's a an example of use case where Toast is instantly overlapped only if the text of the new one is different from the last one, otherwise, it waits a certain amount of time before overlapping it (i.e `SAME_TOAST_DURATION_BEFORE_OVERLAP`):

```
public class SingleToast {
    private static Toast _toast;
    private static String _text;
    private static long _lastToast;
    private static final int SAME_TOAST_DURATION_BEFORE_OVERLAP = 2000; // in ms

    public static void show(Context context, String text, int duration) {
        if (_toast == null) {
            _toast = Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), text, duration);
            _text = text;
        } else {
            if (_text.equals(text)) {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - _lastToast > SAME_TOAST_DURATION_BEFORE_OVERLAP) {
                    _toast.cancel();
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                _text = text;
                _toast.cancel();
                _toast.setText(_text);
            }
        }
        _lastToast = System.currentTimeMillis();
        _toast.show();
    }
}
```