# Show Toast if there is no Toast already showing

Tags: android, runnable, toast, android-toast

I have several buttons that can be clicked on a fragment. After clicking each button I show a Toast message that is exactly the same for each button. Thus if you press 5 different buttons one after another you will layer up 5 toast messages which will end up showing the same message for a long time. What I want to do is show a Toast if there is no Toast currently running.

The method that I use to show the Toast message

```
public void showToastFromBackground(final String message) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

When a button is pressed I simply call `showToastFromBackground("Text to show");`.

What I actually want is something like

```
public void showToastFromBackground(final String message) {
    if(toastIsNotAlreadyRunning)
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    }       
}
```

Comment: what is your second code doing?

Comment: that is what I want. Show the toast if there is no toast already running

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
toast.getView().isShown();
```

Or:

```
if (toast == null || toast.getView().getWindowVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
    // Show a new toast...
}
```

---

EDIT:

```
Toast lastToast = null; // Class member variable

public void showToastFromBackground(final String message) {
    if(isToastNotRunning()) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lastToast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                lastToast.show();
            }
        });
    }       
}

boolean isToastNotRunning() {
    return (lastToast == null || lastToast.getView().getWindowVisibility() != View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: how do I access the toast object. it is running on a separate thread.

Comment: You can store it in a class member variable i.e. `lastToast`

Comment: I edited my answer. The code is not tested, but it might be a start.

Answer (score 2):

Try `isShown()`. It returns a fatal error if no `toast` is `shown`. So you can use `try and catch` the error.

```
//"Toast toast" is declared in the class

 public void showAToast (String st){ 
        try{ 
            toast.getView().isShown();     // true if visible
            toast.setText(st);
        } catch (Exception e) {         // invisible if exception
            toast = Toast.makeText(theContext, st, toastDuration);
        }
        toast.show();  //finally display it
 }
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11441738/3736955).

This does not wait if there is toast already, then show. But it does change active toast's text and show new one immediately without toasts overlapping each other.