# Toast.getView() returns null on Android 11 (API 30)

Tags: android, toast

I just installed the Android R (API 30) image in my emulator to try my app, and it crashed when trying to set the Background color of a Toast.

```
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctxt, msg, duration);
    View view = toast.getView();
    view.setBackgroundColor(0xFF303030);
    TextView tview = view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    tview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    toast.show();
```

This is really strange as in Android Q (API 29) works perfectly.

My build.gradle updated for Android R (API 30)

```
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"
```

Is there a new way to do it??

Comment: This is by design - toast modifications are now deprecated, you can only show raw text: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/toasts

Comment: @Pawel nice catch. getView now returns null

Comment: @Pawel Ok, toast modifications are deprecated. So, whether to want to use one aren't there way to disable showing the its icon?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since Android 11, custom toasts/ toast modifications are deprecated, according to Google to "protect users". Hence why your app in Android 30 is not able to display custom toasts.

From Android Developers documentation:

> Custom toast views are deprecated. Apps can create a standard text toast with the makeText(android.content.Context, java.lang.CharSequence, int)

Comment: Though it comes up as deprecated, you can use it so long as you don't try to show custom toast from the background

Answer (score 9):

You can check before to custumized toast

```
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctxt, msg, duration);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        View view = toast.getView();
        view.setBackgroundColor(0xFF303030);
        TextView tview = view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        tview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    toast.show();
```

Comment: That should be `<=`, not `<` right?

Comment: toast.getView is deprecated.

Comment: @Mattwmaster58 No, that is correct. Because it's deprecated since Android 11

Answer (score 7):

The only way I have found of showing custom toasts from API 30 onwards is by creating them ad hoc.

**XML LAYOUT**
**Customize as needed**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".main_activity">



        <!--Ad hoc toast Textview-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_margin="18dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ad_hoc_toast_background"
            android:textColor="#1e1e1e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/ad_hoc_toast_textview"
            tools:text="Temporary message bla bla bla ..."/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**TOAST BACKGROUND**    (ad_hoc_toast_background.xml)
**Customize as needed**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:shape="rectangle">

        <size
                 android:width="220dp"
                 android:height="100dp"/>
        <corners
                 android:radius="25dp"
            />

        <solid
                 android:color="#e6ffffff"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

**Define the *show_ad_hoc_toast()* method**

```
private void show_ad_hoc_toast(final TextView ad_hoc_toast_textview, String text){


    //Set the text
    ad_hoc_toast_textview.setText(text);


    //Create alpha animation
    AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f);

    //Set duration
    animation1.setDuration(300);

    //Set that the animation changes persist once the animation finishes
    animation1.setFillAfter(true);


    //Set on AnimationEnd Listner
    animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){}
        @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){}
        @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation){

            //After 2250 millis -> hide the toast
            new CountDownTimer(2250, 1) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){}
                public void onFinish() {hide_ad_hoc_toast(ad_hoc_toast_textview);}
            }.start();


        }

    });


    //Make the view visible
    ad_hoc_toast_textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    //Start animation
    ad_hoc_toast_textview.startAnimation(animation1);


}
```

**Define the *hide_ad_hoc_toast()* method**

```
private void hide_ad_hoc_toast(final TextView ad_hoc_toast_textview){


    //Create alpha animation
    AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);

    //Set duration
    animation1.setDuration(300);

    //Set that the animation changes persist once the animation finishes
    animation1.setFillAfter(true);


    //Set on AnimationEnd Listner
    animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
        @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
        @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            //Make the view gone
            ad_hoc_toast_textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    });



    //Start animation
    ad_hoc_toast_textview.startAnimation(animation1);



}
```

**Call the method from your code when needed**

```
//Find ad_hoc_toast textview
TextView ad_hoc_toast_textview = findViewById(R.id.ad_hoc_toast_textview);

//Define the text to be shown
String text = "This is the custom toast message"

//Show the ad_hoc toast
show_ad_hoc_toast(ad_hoc_toast_textview, text);
```

**RESULT**
[image: RESULT]

Comment: Could you add screenshot?

Comment: Done ; )
Note that now you can customize the textview or the toast's background as needed.

Comment: Is it possible to call this from running background service?

Comment: I am afraid not. This would only show the "toast" as long as the activity that contains it is active.

Comment: Will this toast persist if another new dialog fragment is diplayed? For example playFragment.show(AppContext.supportFragmentManager()!!,"play")

Answer (score 7):

@pvalle & @Aayush Panda, It works for me in Android 11. Please check below code

```
public static void showCenterToastMessage(Context context, String msg) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,null);
        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(msg);
        text.setPadding(20,0,20,0);
        text.setTextSize(18);
        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        Toast toast = new Toast(context);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
    }
```

layout is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have an app which uses toasts extensively.  I used this approach when migrating it to Android 11.  It worked very well for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the layout for `custom_toast`

Comment: @Mattwmaster58 Layout file added.

Answer (score 3):

The solution with setting a custom `view` on `Toast` is deprecated for **API level 30**

Documentation says

> This method was deprecated in API level 30. Custom toast views are
> deprecated. **Apps can create a standard text toast with the
> makeText(android.content.Context, java.lang.CharSequence, int) method**,
> **or use a Snackbar when in the foreground**. Starting from Android
> Build.VERSION_CODES#R, apps targeting API level Build.VERSION_CODES#R
> or higher that are in the background will not have custom toast views
> displayed.

There is a walkaround though which still works and is not deprecated

```
Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<font color='red'>custom toast message</font>", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Html color tag can also be `<font color='#ff6347'>`

Comment: It's just change the Text , How about the background ?

Answer (score 0):

WindowManager interface can be an alternative to the toast after the Android 11 limitations.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager

But you just need user permission to display custom messages over the apps.