# Android Toast Instance View Return Null

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Xamarin android Toast View Rerun Null.

Here is the code snippet

```
Toast t = Toast.MakeText(context, message, shorOrLong);
            Color c = color;
            ColorMatrixColorFilter CM = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new float[]
                {
                0,0,0,0,c.R,
                0,0,0,0,c.G,
                0,0,0,0,c.B,
                0,0,0,1,0
                });
            t.View.Background.SetColorFilter(CM);
            t.Show();
```

**here t.View is null.**

[image]

for that I am getting null reference exception. Any kind of help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not so

```
 t.getView().getBackground().setColorFilter(CM);
    t.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Snice Android 11, custom toast is deprecated .

We can't set the background color on the toast , if you want to customize the background , use [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar) instead .

Refer to

[Toast.getView() returns null on Android 11 (API 30)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62884286/toast-getview-returns-null-on-android-11-api-30)

[Method setView is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312296/method-setview-is-deprecated)