# Xamarin Toast.MakeText change Color

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-toast

How can I change the background color of a Toast in a Xamarin Forms Application?

I've tried this code on Android 11:

```
Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
string message = "Hello toast!";
ToastLength duration = ToastLength.Short;

Toast t = Toast.MakeText(context, message, duration);
System.Drawing.Color c = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Green;
ColorMatrixColorFilter CM = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new float[]
{
    0,0,0,0,c.R,
    0,0,0,0,c.G,
    0,0,0,0,c.B,
    0,0,0,1,0            
});
t.View.Background.SetColorFilter(CM);
t.Show();
```

But I get the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: which **specific** line throws the exception?  At a glance it doesn't even seem like that code should compile.

Comment: this has also been asked numerous times: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+toast+background+color+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom toast views are deprecated since Android 11. So the value of `t.View` in your code is null.

Just like the official document says:

> Custom toast views are deprecated. Apps can create a standard text toast with the makeText(android.content.Context, java.lang.CharSequence, int)

You can check the following case:[Toast.getView() returns null on Android 11 (API 30)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62884286/toast-getview-returns-null-on-android-11-api-30)